# Random freezing on Dell Optiplex 780

Tags: windows-xp, dell-optiplex

I ordered a batch of these for work (10 machines).  Some of them got Windows 7 and the rest got Windows XP SP3.  The ones that were loaded up with windows 7 are working fine but the ones that have Win XP SP3 are randomly locking up throughout the day.

The freeze can be at the start of the day and never happen again, or it could be a couple times throughout the day.

I've checked everything having to do with the device drivers and everything looks fine.  I'm wanting to think its a program not working well with windows but I could be wrong.

The only programs installed on these machines are Win XP, Office 2007, Adobe Reader X, Java, Flash, and some very basic printer drivers.  The user's aren't administrators so they can't install anything themselves to cause any changes.

The freezes themselves just sort of leave the computer at a screen image and you can't interact with the keyboard or mouse, the hard drive isn't reading.  The only fix is to hard power down the machine and power it back up.

Comment: Have you looked at the Event Viewer ? Have you installed the latest [drivers](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?os=WW1&catid=-1&dateid=-1&impid=-1&osl=EN&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&servicetag=&SystemID=PLX_780&hidos=WLH&hidlang=en&TabIndex=&scanSupported=False&scanConsent=False) from Dell ?

Comment: I'm keeping an eye on their eventviewers but nothing is really coming up, and yes all the drivers on the machine are the most up to date.

Comment: It looks like I may have found my answer in windows search service.  It seems to keep locking up on these machines so I'm going to remove that update and see how things go.

Comment: Sounds just like a problem a few years back Dell had with the 760's, wound up being a bios and network driver issue, it took Dell a few weeks to get it sorted out with a bios update and network driver update.

Comment: have your tried to reinstall the windows? maybe its a corruption with all the devices? i'm not sure that is possible but you never know

Answer (score 1):

make sure your pc has no cooling problem and then,

reset bios settings

boot in safe mode

disable network controllers

reboot

install safe-older network drivers